# Formation of enamine for unsymmetrical cyclohexanone derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Question:

[image]

Answer given: D

My answer: C

My reasoning - I outlined the following steps in the reaction:

1. Nucleophilic attack of pyrrolidine on the carbonyl, leading to the carbon atom now having one $\ce{-OH}$ group and attached to the nitrogen of pyrrolidine.
2. Heat is mentioned, so I assumed it is for dehydration. **Dehydration, as far as I know, should result in the most stable double bond i.e. the one with maximum alkyl substituents.** So I formed an enamine with double bond on the right side.
3. Nucleophilic attack of enamine's $\ce{C=C}$ on the leftmost carbon atom of $\ce{H2C=CH-CN}$, which is Michael addition.
4. $\ce{H3O^+}$ to provide proton to the carbanion.

These steps lead to the formation of C. For D to be formed, **step 2 must be altered, and the less substituted (and less stable) double bond must be formed.** Why does that happen?

I also can see that the nucleophile $\ce{C=C}$ is sterically hindered in step 3. That will lower the yield of step 3. However, that steric hindrance or comfort **in step 3** should not affect the formation of $\ce{C=C}$ **in previous step 2**.

I am also open to the fact that the answer key given might be wrong. But in case the key is right and I am wrong, I would like to know why my step 2 is wrong.

Comment: I think the answer key is probably wrong (judging from the other options it seems like you really had to decide between the 2 enols really. $\alpha-H$ calculation makes it clear that we should prefer C. What is this cis-trans it is mentioning in opt. B and D? I don't see an stereogenic center..

Comment: @TRC I can see 2 pathways for this reaction, one through additon reaction(in first step) other  through removal of acidic H and my prof had taught, that in such condtions carry out acid base first as this reaction is faster. I also doubt whether acc to your mech dehydration would not happen, I might be wrong about this though.

Comment: @Rishi That's not really cis-trans though. I should have added db bond with cis/trans though

Comment: @napstablook Thank you for your input. The cis-trans is probably referring to isomerism with respect to the cyclohexane ring. My main textbook uses that term to refer to groups around ring on same side or opposite sides (for example, as in 1,2-dimethylcyclohexane). Not sure if that term has become obsolete now or not.

Comment: @Rishi I wasn't able to understand the other pathway you suggested. Where will the acidic H be removed from?

Comment: @TRC 1. Removal of acidic H by pyrrolidene from the less substituted alpha carbon then this Nu- reacts as you mentioned in step 3 and follows

Comment: @napstablook I just asked for the test paper's solutions from my teacher. I checked and it has the same mechanism as I suggested, only with the step 2 double bond formed on the other side. They have not mentioned any reason for that.

Comment: @TRC you can put their mech in the post if it has other noticeable details else the post is fine as it is.

Comment: @Rishi I knew only strong bases (like NaOH or LDA) were sufficiently basic to remove the hydrogen from alpha-carbon. In the pathway you mention wouldn't the equilibrium lie largely to the reactant side?

Comment: @Rishi No, nothing. It has the same mechanism, just with the structures included.

Comment: 1 last point, this is a really bad question, the h3o+ at the end will hydrolyse the cyanide. Usually if you have to question the author's intention more than think about the question it is not a good qn. :(

Comment: @napstablook True, it should have worked out if they had mentioned mild workup.

Comment: @napstablook Absolutely agreed! It's not from a book though, it's from a coaching institute's mock test for a national level exam. I've found a lot of their other questions to be meaningless as well.

Comment: @napstablook  the H+ will hydrolyse the enamine very much more easily than the nitrile. Mild aq acid at rt hydrolyses enamines, you need forcing conditions (conc acid, high temp) to hydrolyse nitriles. It is entirely possible to be selective about which group is hydrolysed.

Comment: @Waylander Yes, the enamine *does* get hydrolyzed when $\ce{H3O^+}$ is added - that's why the options again depict cyclohexanone. As for the concentration and temperature, that's another fault of this exam - they give us only half the experimental information and expect us to know what products will be formed.

Comment: @Waylander I agree, I still think it should be mentioned though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this site [here](https://pharmaxchange.info/2011/04/producing-and-using-imines-and-enamines/) citing Carey & Sundberg and Morrison & Boyd

"In case of 2-methyl cyclohexanone, this planarity would cause steric clashes between the methyl group and the pyrrolidine hydrogen atoms. Due to this, formation of the less stable 6-position carbanion is preferred and hence forces reactions to proceed at this position."

[image]

Comment: In turn, "*site here*" cites Carey & Sundberg and Morrison & Boyd. Referencing primary sources (i.e. these textbooks) is preferred.

Comment: The answer is D as @Waylander has noted. Here is the original Stork paper: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00885a021

Comment: @Waylander I think that while this is a problem in normal situations, I would rather take heat as an assumption that the reaction is under thermodynamic control and only final product matters..